# python: multiplication in for loop skipped on second iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, multiplication, sieve

I am trying to implement the Sieve of Euler (as described on [programmingpraxis.com](https://programmingpraxis.com/2011/02/25/sieve-of-euler/)).I have code that runs fine on the first iteration, however on the next iteration my multiplication is skipped for some reason that escapes me (probably just missing some python-behavior there that is common sense to a more experienced programmer)
I am running this:

```
import numpy as np
#set up parameters
primes = [2]
startval = 2
stopval = 10000
firstrun = True
candidates = np.arange(start=startval,stop=stopval+1,step=1)
#actual program
for idx in range(int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(stopval)))): #only up until sqrt(n) needs checking
    print('pos1')
    print(candidates)
    print(candidates[0])
    times = candidates[0]*candidates
    print(times)
    diffset = list(set(candidates)^set(times))
    if len(diffset) is not 0: #to make sure the program quits properly if diffset=[]
        primes.append(diffset.pop(0))
        print('pos2')
        print(diffset)
        candidates = diffset
        print('pos3')
        print(candidates)
    else:
        break
print(primes)
```

The various print statements are just so i can get a grasp on whats going on. Note the first outputs are fine, the interesting part starts the second time pos1 is printed. my candidates are updated just as I want them to, the new first element is also correct. So my question is:

Why is `times = candidates[0]*candidates`apparently skipped on the second iteration?

Please note: I am not asking for a "scratch your code, copy this working and faster, better, nicer code" answer. There are plenty of python implementations out there, I want to do this myself. I think I am missing a fairly important concept of python here, and thats why my code doesn't behave.

(Should anyone ask: No, this is not a homework assignment. I am using a bit of python at my workplace and like to do these sorts of things at home to get better at coding)

Comment: It seems that on the first iteration candidates is a "numpy.ndarray" object but on the second it is a list. if you convert the diffset to a numpy.ndarray before assigning it to the candidates variable does it help?

Comment: That was exactly the issue, as FlyingTeller pointed out as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code. Looking at the output of `times` in line 14 you can see that after the first iteration the operation is performed, but not in the way you intended to. The list `times` is just three times the list `candidates` put after one another. To elaborate:

**1st iteration**

```
candidates = np.arange(start=startval,stop=stopval+1,step=1)
```

so candidates is a numpy array. Doing

```
candidates*candidates[0]
```

is the same as `candidates*2`, which is "numpy_array*number", which is just element-wise multiplication.
Now further down you do

```
diffset = list(set(candidates) ^ set(times))
....
candidates = diffset
```

which sets up:

**2nd iteration**
`candidates` is now a **list** (see above). Doing

```
candidates*candidates[0]
```

is just `candidates*3` which is now "list*number" which in python is not "multiply each list element by number", but instead: "create new list as being original list concatenated number times with itself". This is why you don't see the output you expected.

To fix this, simply do:

```
candidates = np.array(diffset)
```

Comment: Ahh, well spotted, thanks for clarifying! That indeed is a difference, and I should've noticed that. Accepting. EDIT: shows no error. Reading is important :) Read np.ndarray instad of np.array

Comment: You might have to filter the elements from diffset that are larger than stopval. For example if you have candidates = 2...100 in the first iteration, then times will contain 4...200 and diffset will contain all values from 102...200 that you don't want

Comment: Additionally, I think your candidates list will not be empty in the end, but might contain values > sqrt(stopval) that are valid primes and need to be added to the list

Comment: Oh yes. another (should be) obvious flaw of my code. Thanks again for the assistance. consider my problems solved for now.